# Vue.js v-if with OR doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabs, logical-operators

There's a logical mistake in my code, but I don't understand why.

I want to hide a tab called `History` if a user is in a group called `BasicSport` or if he is in a group called `Basic`.

I implemented the tabs via:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row" >
      <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-bottom:20px" @click="changeSelectedComp">Back</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:1000px" @click="EditMode">Edit</button>
    </div>

    <vue-tabs>
      <v-tab title="Basic">
        <app-players></app-players>
      </v-tab>
      <v-tab v-if="(!basicGroup || !basicSportGroup)" title="History">
        <app-histories></app-histories>
      </v-tab>
      <v-tab v-if="!basicGroup" title="Timetable">
        <app-timetables></app-timetables>
      </v-tab>
      <v-tab v-if="!basicGroup" title="Scholarship">
        <app-scholarship></app-scholarship>
      </v-tab>
    </vue-tabs>
  </div>
</template>
```

In this case the `History` tab still shows up even if the user is in the `BasicSport` group:

[image]

But if I write

```
<v-tab v-if="!basicSportGroup" title="History">
```

the tab doesn't show up:

[image]

I don't understand why the second one works, but the first one doesn't since the  OR isn't exclusive.
How can one hide the `History` tab if a user is in  `BasicSport` or if he is in the `Basic` group?.

Here's the [full component](https://codeshare.io/Gk1yQ4)

Comment: Try replacing `||` with`&&`

Comment: From what you say with words, you want to hide (`!`) when `a || b` is true (if it's one of the two cases).

Which means `!(a || b)`, which is the same as `!a && !b`. With any of the above, whenever `a` or `b` are truthy, you're hiding the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to **hide** it if "a user is in a group called `BasicSport` or if he is in a group called `Basic`" (1)

So you want to **show** it if the user is NOT in `BasicSport` AND NOT in `Basic`. (2)

Your logic should be :

```
(1)
<v-tab v-if="!(basicGroup || basicSportGroup)" title="History">
  <app-histories></app-histories>
</v-tab>
```

or

```
(2)
<v-tab v-if="!basicGroup && !basicSportGroup" title="History">
  <app-histories></app-histories>
</v-tab>
```

Comment: You can learn more here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `&&` operator instead of `||` operator as you want to show only if not in `BasicSport` and not in `Basic`.

```
<v-tab v-if="!basicGroup && !basicSportGroup" title="History">
    <app-histories></app-histories>
</v-tab>
```

Or you can also try `!(basicGroup || basicSportGroup)`